# Chrome image opacity bug [strange line appears]

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opacity

I am encountering this strange bug. But only in Chrome so far. Firefox and IE11 are doing fine.
The problem is this:

When I hover over an image in my portfolio, the opacity drops from 0.7 to 0.2. When the transition is done, a strange line appears that looks like it isnt affected by the opacity attribute.

*System specs:*

- Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1 // Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m
- Screen resolution: 1920 x 1080
- Video card: nVidea GeForce GT650m

---

Here is a [**link to a demo site**](http://www.baasdesign.nl/projects/Bootstrap/).

Here you can see the line in a screenshot:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzaqwhzyv9h8j7n/glitch-x.jpg?dl=0]

And here is a working code snippet:

```css
.grid figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -0.135em;
  width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.grid figure figcaption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.grid figure a {
  z-index: 1000;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.grid figure h2 {
  word-spacing: -0.15em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.grid figure h2 span {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -1px;
  font-size: 31px;
}
.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid figure p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68.5%;
  clear: left;
}
figure.effect-lily img {
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-lily figcaption {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10%;
}
figure.effect-lily h2,
figure.effect-lily p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 40px, 0);
}
figure.effect-lily h2 {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
}
figure.effect-lily p {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.35s;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
figure.effect-lily:hover img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
figure.effect-lily:hover p {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
figure.effect-lily:hover img,
figure.effect-lily:hover h2,
figure.effect-lily:hover p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-lily:hover p {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
}
figure.effect-lily p.cursive {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<figure class="effect-lily double">
  <img src="http://www.baasdesign.nl/projects/Bootstrap/images/5.jpg" alt="img01" />
  <figcaption>
    <h2><span>Stichting</span>Werkartaal</h2>
    <p>Meer in reïntegratie</p>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="werkartaal.html">View more</a>
</figure>
```

Any one ANY clue to what this could be?

Comment: Cannot replicate.  Just tried it in Chrome 38 on Windows 7 and there's no visual glitching.

Comment: Looks ok to me on Chrome 38 OS X 10.10

Comment: Mr. Llama What is your screenresolution?

Steve Sanders , looks good here aswell on Chrome - OSX. Only windows 7 - Chrome 38

Comment: Can't reproduce (Win7 Home Premium SP1, Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m)

Comment: Looks good to me as well (GC 38.0.2125.111, Mac OS X 10.7.5). Do you have a browser zoom active (you can reset it by pressing STRG+0)?

Comment: @WesselGrift - Do you get this issue when in incognito mode? i.e. with no extensions active?